# android app with opengl navigation element, background image and video

Tags: android, video, opengl-es

i have done a view apps with setContetnView and the xml layouts... Actually I do some steps in opengl. Now i want to have one background image, a video area an the opengl 3d navigation element beside the video area to control the videos.

Is it necessary to do the whole work in opengl, or is it possible to put the opengl part over an existing view?

Where can I find more infos on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can place the `OpenGL` view over top of the other views. I worked on an app that placed a OpenGLView over top of a `VideoView`. There may be some performance issues, so I would recommend adding the hardware acceleration attribute to your `AndroidManifest.xml` (under the application element):

```
android:hardwareAcceleration="true"
```

One thing that you will need to know to get the layout you expect is that the `SurfaceView`s do not conform to the normal view hierarchy, so you will want to set the *z-order* of the view programmatically, using the method [setZOrderOnTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop%28boolean%29):

```
mVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(false);
mOpenGLView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```